# Use tikzpicture vector lengths to specify node dimension

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I would like to create a node with `minimum width=αx`, where x is the length of the x-coordinate vector specified in the tikzpicture environment, e.g. `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.1cm,y=2.5ex]`. Is this possible?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I'm not sure how to reference that parameter later, but you can use `\newcommand\xlen{0.1cm}` just before the `tikzpicture` environment, then start with `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\xlen,y=2.5ex]` and use (for example) `\node[minimum width=17*\xlen]` when defining the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495231/184389), you can define variables to set your x and y scales and a style for your node as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\unitx}{1cm}
\newcommand{\unity}{1cm}

\tikzset{%
    box/.style 2 args = {%
        rectangle,
        draw,
        minimum width  = #1*\unitx,
        minimum height = #2*\unity
    },
    every tikzpicture/.append style = {
        x = \unitx,
        y = \unity
    }
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \node[box={2}{3}] at (0, 0) {Hello};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\renewcommand{\unitx}{5cm}
\renewcommand{\unity}{3cm}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \node[box={2}{3}] at (0, 0) {Hello};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With this, you impose a given scale on `x` and `y` for every `tikzpicture` environment and you define a style for a rectangle node with `minimum width` and `minimum height` based on this scale.

The scales are stored in the `\unitx` and `\unity` variables that you can redefine anywhere in your document to change the scale.

If you do not want to apply the scaling globally, remove the `every tikzpicture` argument of the `\tikzset` command and apply the scaling locally as in the following example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\unitx}{2cm}
\newcommand{\unity}{1cm}

\tikzset{%
    box/.style 2 args = {%
        rectangle,
        draw,
        minimum width  = #1*\unitx,
        minimum height = #2*\unity
    }
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[x = \unitx, y = \unity]

        \node[box={2}{3}] at (0, 0) {Hello};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see that my question is essentially the same as the one you linked. As with the answers to that question, your answer is a workaround, but the nagging question remains: Why do dimensionless node dimensions not use the `x`/`y` lengths?

Comment: Ak ok, the answer to (this question)[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50991/use-the-coordinate-system-to-set-size-of-a-node?rq=1] is elucidating.